# Unable to play local video from iPhone

Tags: objective-c, ios, video, mpmovieplayercontroller

I'm having trouble playing a video on the iPhone. I have a file in the app bundle and I am trying to play it in a `MPMoviePlayerController` but it is just displaying a black screen. This is the following code:

```
-(UIView*)createVideoPlayerOfWidth:(CGFloat)width
{
    // The width for one of these can be half of the max width
    //CGFloat widthAndHeight = width / 2.0f;

    // TODO: Create a video player
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myVideo" ofType:@"mov"]];
    MPMoviePlayerController *playerController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
    [playerController prepareToPlay];
    [playerController setShouldAutoplay:NO];
    [playerController setScalingMode:MPMovieScalingModeAspectFit];
    [playerController setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleEmbedded];
    [playerController setRepeatMode:MPMovieRepeatModeNone];

    // Resize the thumbnail of the video
    [[playerController view] setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, width, width)];

    return [playerController view];
}
```

It is returning a valid URL (pathForResource would return nil if it couldn't find the file). I am displaying it to the screen by just adding a subView (the view returned by the function) to a scroll view. I've been trying to solve this for ages now and am getting nowhere. Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure its a valid iOS movie file? Have you tested it with one you know works

Comment: It was a video that I recorded from an iPhone and uploaded to my laptop. I just assumed seeing as though .MOV is Apple's thing it would work on their device?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you are retaining a reference to the `MPMoviePlayerController` instance:

- If this is an ARC project, then `playerController` will be destroyed when `createVideoPlayerOfWidth` returns, and your video probably won't play. You should store the player in a `strong` instance variable or property.

  You could add something like this to the top of your view controller file:

  ```
  @interface MyViewController ()
  @property (nonatomic,retain) MPMoviePlayerController *player;
  @end
  ```

  And insert this after you create the `MPMoviewPlayerController` instance:

  ```
  self.player = playerController;
  ```
- If you're not using ARC, this is probably not the problem, but you should still keep a reference in an instance variable, so that you can release it later.

Comment: This is an ARC project, yes. I changed it to `__strong MPMoviePlayerController` but the problem is still happening.

Comment: No, you need to actually store it in a instance variable of your class. That way the reference is retained longer than the scope of this one method. At the moment, the compiler doesn't see any point in keeping `playerController` around any longer than this one method call.

Comment: Sorry it has taken me a while to reply. I'm trying to do this in a category (we have coredata objects and then do catagories on these so our functions aren't deleted if we regenerate the .m & h). I'm struggling to create a `strong` reference in the category. Would you have any ideas about how I could do it?

Comment: It seems like a separate issue -- I'm not sure how to accomplish that. The only thing I can think of seems to be to use Objective-C runtime functions to do the dirty work. See [Adding Properties to an Objective-C Category](http://www.davidhamrick.com/2012/02/12/Adding-Properties-to-an-Objective-C-Category.html).